# Constexpr / compile-time constant expressions bugs

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, compiler-errors, constexpr

I get the following error in my project upon compiling. Tried everything but unable to resolve this.

**Reproduced the error here:**
**https://replit.com/join/egfoiwpgig-darshanpandhi**

## Error

error: constexpr variable 'noOfTiles' must be initialized by a constant expression

## Relevant Code

### Board.h

```
# pragma once

class Board {
private:

public:
    static constexpr int getTotalNoOfTiles();
};
```

### Board.cpp

```
# include "Board.h"


constexpr int Board::getTotalNoOfTiles() {
    return 21;  // calculation simplified for the sake of example
}
```

### Player.h

```
# pragma once

# include "Board.h"


class Player {
private:
    static constexpr int noOfTiles = Board::getTotalNoOfTiles();   // this needs to be constexpr because I will be using noOfTiles as an array size in this same file
};
```

## Question

Isn't `Board::getTotalNoOfTiles()` a constant expression since it simply returns 21. Isn't this a compile-time constant?

**Reproduced the error here: https://replit.com/join/egfoiwpgig-darshanpandhi**

Comment: Why do you define the `Player` class twice? Isn't that what the header file is for?

Comment: And please try to create a [mre] to show us. There's nothing in the shown code that `#include` the `Player.h` header file, so he shown code will not have the error you claim at the location you claim.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/91Pn3Gd5v). Suspect either `Board::getTotalNoOfTiles()` is not defined in **Board.h**, or you have a circular dependency in your headers, and/or the compiler produced other errors/warnings before this one which you did not read or show. We have to take your word on how `getTotalNoOfTiles` is defined, as you have not even shown its definition. Is the entire contents of **Board.cpp** in your question a copy/paste error? The file is apparently identical to **Player.h**

Comment: I made a mistake by including the `Player` class twice. Fixed it by replacing with the correct `Board.cpp` file

Comment: @paddy
 Added reproducible link that shows the same error I get

Comment: @GAMERZ - Replit requires a log-in, so not helpful.

Comment: @BoP Can you just create a throw-away account to view the code

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` by itself isn't enough.  The compiler needs to be able to get the value at compile time, so the definition of `getTotalNoOfTiles` needs to be in your .h file.  Inline of course.